# Reduce function length when exporting module

Tags: node.js, code-complexity

I am exporting a function for a module such that I can pass variables into the module.  However our code analyzer is reporting that the function is too long.

Typically I am doing this to pass my express app and some configuration into a file that will define some routes.  I usually have different route files for each resource to just give some separation:

```
routes/authors.js
routes/books.js
...
etc
```

Inside authors.js:

```
module.exports = function(app, configuration) {

  app.post('/authors', ...


  app.get('/authors', ...


  app.get('/authors/:id', ...

}
```

This works great but I end up with a very long function.  Not a huge deal as the function is comprised of many same functions for each route.  But static code analyzes complain about the function length.

Sure maybe this is something that should just be ignored.  But I also want to make sure this is not a good opportunity to make the code a little better, as maybe (just maybe) the code analyzer is correct.

Is there a better way to export a function in a module and avoid the really long function?  And by 'better' I am looking for something that might be a standard or convention that I am not following, I don't want to change the code if I am already following nodejs/express conventions.

Comment: is `...` a function expression? are you defining it in `...` or just referencing a function?

Answer (score 1):

The way I have been doing it is by putting my route methods in a separate controller file.

Example authors.controller.js:

```
module.exports = {
    getAuthorsById: function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('authors');
    },
    getAuthors: function(req, res, next) {
    },
    // Now if for some reason I need to configuration object passed into
    // the controller method I can simply return a function.
    postAuthor: function(conf) {
        return function(req, res, next) {
            if(conf.x) {
                res.render(conf.y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

example authors.routes.js:

```
var ctrl = require('./authors.controller.js');

module.exports = function(app, conf) {
    app.get('/authors/:id', ctrl.getAuthorsById);
    app.get('/authors', ctrl.getAuthors);
    // And then pass in the configuration object when needed.
    app.post('/authors', ctrl.postAuthor(conf));
}();
```

This way the function the routes are defined in isn't massive in itself though the controller file can still be quite big.